# Python regular expression to replace strings in csv

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file formatted as below:

```
   cat, mammal[1]
   shark, fish[2]
   dog, mammal[3]
   tiger, mammal[4]
   salmon, fish[5]
```

I would like to replace all the rows containing mammal along with the square brackets.

The output should be as follows:

```
cat, mam
shark, fish[2]
dog, mam
tiger, mam
salmon, fish[5]
```

so far I have a code to read/write the csv file:

```
import csv


with open('animals.csv', 'r') as fin, open("out.csv",'w') as fout:
        writer = csv.writer(fout)
        for row in csv.reader(fin):
            re.sub(???) #stuck at writing the regular expression
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Why *regex*? Just using `str.replace('mammal[1]', 'mam')` will suffice your requirement

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri presumably because the index is not always `1`.

Comment: I have a huge list of rows in the csv file(the csv below is just an example of the fomat), replacing them like that would take days

Comment: @Fanna1119 I don't see how running a `str.replace` would take days... If you want performance, see my solution using `writerows` and a generator comprehension. But I suspect my code will choke on the input format ... that you didn't share with us.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex for your replacement:

```
for row in csv.reader(fin):
    row[1] = re.sub(r'(\s*mam)mal\[\d+\]', '\1', row[1])
    writer.writerow(row)
```

See [demonstration](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%5Cs*mam)mal%5C%5B%5Cd%2B%5C%5D&test_string=mammal%5B1%5D%0A%20mammal%5B2%5D%0Amammal%5B3%5D&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex here:

```
for row in csv.reader(fin):
    if row[1].startswith("mammal["):
       row[1] = "mam"
```

Performance wise it's best because

- no regex
- string replacement only if matches, left unchanged otherwise

or even faster with a generator comprehension and `writerows`:

```
with open('animals.csv', 'r') as fin, open("out.csv",'w') as fout:
    csv.writer(fout).writerows([row[0],"mam"] if row[1].starswith("mammal[") else row for row in csv.reader(fin))
```

note: seems that there's a leading space in the second column. In which case, add a space in front of search/replace strings.

Comment: It may be difficult to get a perfect replacement for the (arbitrary) leading spaces before the matching item with this approach, otherwise, this is super!

Comment: I suspect that the file is just an example, spaces added for readability. Thanks for your comment.